# Nobody knows GAU Numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence

## Let me introduce you to GAU numbers

```
GAU(1) = 1  
GAU(2) = 1122  
GAU(3) = 1122122333  
GAU(4) = 11221223331223334444  
GAU(6) = 11221223331223334444122333444455555122333444455555666666  
...  
GAU(10) = 11221223331223334444122333444455555122333444455555666666122333444455555666666777777712233344445555566666677777778888888812233344445555566666677777778888888899999999912233344445555566666677777778888888899999999910101010101010101010
```

## **This challenge is pretty simple!**

Given an integer n>0, find the number of digits of GAU(n)

## Example

Let's make **GAU(4)**
we take the following steps (until we get to 4) and concatenate them

```
[1][122][122333][1223334444]
```

you must write every number as many times as its value, but you have to count every time from 1

Let's try to make **GAU(5)**
we will have to count from 1 to 1

```
[1]
```

then from 1 to 2 (but **repeating every number as many times as its value**)

```
[122]
```

then from 1 to 3

```
[122333]
```

then from 1 to 4

```
[1223334444]
```

and finally from 1 to 5 (this is the **last step** because we want to find GAU(**5**))

```
[122333444455555]
```

Now we take all these steps and concatenate them
the result is GAU(5)

```
11221223331223334444122333444455555
```

**We are interested in the number of digits of these GAU numbers.**

## Test cases

***Input⟼Output***

```
n   ⟼ Length(GAU(n))

1   ⟼ 1  
2   ⟼ 4  
3   ⟼ 10  
10  ⟼ 230   
50  ⟼ 42190  
100 ⟼ 339240  
150 ⟼ 1295790
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.
Shortest code in bytes will win.

If you still have any questions please let me know.
I really want everyone here to understand this magic-hidden-complex pattern

Comment: What does GAU stand for?

Comment: G is for GAU, A and U are just there for no reason

Comment: Up until n=9, the lengths are tetrahedral numbers, but beyond that the multi-digit numbers get in the way of a simple closed form

Comment: FYI your test case says `n   ⟼ Length(GUA(n))`, not GAU(n).

Comment: @numbermaniac this was an edit by Sanchises. Just above the test cases I state with bold letters "We are interested in the number of digits of these GAU numbers".

Comment: @Jose I know, I was just saying `GAU` is spelt as `GUA` :)

Comment: @numbermaniac thanks for spotting this. GUA numbers are totally different. They haven't been invented yet!

Answer (score 14):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
∫∫l*+
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMjJCJXUyMjJCbCorRiUwQTEwJXUyMDFEckY_) - this expects to be called as a function with the input on the stack and the input box empty.
7 byte alternative taking the input from the input box:

```
0.∫∫l*+
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MC4ldTIyMkIldTIyMkJsKis_,inputs=MTA_)

```
0      push 0
 .     push the input
  ∫    iterate over a range 1..POP (input) inclusive, pusing the current number
   ∫    iterate over 1..POP (above loops number) inclusive, pusing the current number
    l    push that numbers length without popping the number
     *   multiply the length by the number
      +  add to the zero, or whatever it is now
```

Comment: `push that numbers length without popping the number` nice

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
f n=sum[j*length(show j)|i<-[1..n],j<-[1..i]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7a4NDc6SysnNS@9JEOjOCO/XCFLsybTRjfaUE8vL1YnC8LKjI39n5uYmadgq5CSr8DFmZtY4KugUVCUmVeil6apAFJiaBCLKW5qoGNoAMSmBrH/AQ)

Comment: A bit more unreadable but one byte cheaper: [TIO](https://tio.run/##DcMxDoAgDADAr3RgEE2I7sDiM4wD0SpGKMbW@Hz0kouBT0yp1g3I8ZMVL4FS0@leNa22rU9Iu0TDsbxW@Wkwhuaaw0Hg4LoPEjCw/W8MKzhrYUcZCwmScB36Dw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 166 bytes

```
<>(((()()())({}){})())<>{({}[()]<({}({}<<>({}[()])((){[()](<()>)}{}){{}((((({})({})){}{}){}))<>(({}<({}())>){()<({}[({})])>}{})(<>)}{}<>>({}({})())))>)}{}({}<{}{}{}>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xCoAwDER/JzcIOriF/Ih0qIMgioNr6LfXO5smJG3vXva3ns903PXq3cMY0IFlA5OTR/KyGYqzM5268QCqU4O5IdDkoUQhL4uMAYLg9AoBatPgP4V/BSGV@Y/wiLFHyzGwcoqULdD7ss4f)

#### Explanation

```
<>(((()()())({}){})())<>           # Initialize second stack with 9 and 10
{({}[()]<                          # Do main loop n times:
  ({}
    ({}
      <
        <>({}[()])                 # Subtract 1 from counter to next power of 10
        ((){[()](<()>)}{}){        # If reached a power of 10 (say, 10^k):
          {}((((({})({})){}{}){})) # Multiply existing (10^k*0.9) by 10 and push twice
          <>                       # On first stack
          (
            ({}<({}())>)           # Increment length of numbers
            {()<({}[({})])>}{}     # Divide length of new set of numbers by this length
          )                        # Add together to get new set of numbers length
        (<>)}  
      {}<>>  
      ({}({})())                   # Add number length to number set length
    )                              # Add number set length to new segment length
  )                                # Add new segment length to total length
>)}                                # End main loop
{}({}<{}{}{}>)                     # Put result on stack by itself
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
ṁLΣQḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HORp9ziwMf7lj8//9/QwMA)

**Explanation**

```
ṁ  map over
 L  length
  Σ  sum list
   Q  all sublists
    ḣ  range 1 .. N
```

Comment: Nice algorithm!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Rx`ƤDFL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z@oIuHYEhc3n////xsaAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
LŒJJg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5@gkL6/0//8NDQA)

**Explanation**

```
L      # push [1 .. a]
 Œ     # all substrings (a)
  J    # numbers to strings (inner)
   J   # numbers to strings (outer)
    g  # length
```

Comment: Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(len(`i`)*i*(x-i+1)for i in range(1,x+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyMnNU8jITNBUytTS6NCN1PbUDMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNQpwIoqPkfLhxtqGOkY6xjaKBjagAkgdjUINaKi7OgKDOvRCNNIxOoGAA)

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyMnNU8jQbcuM0FTC0hqaVToZmqm5RcpZCpk5ikUJealp2pUaGr@hwtFG@oY6RjrGBromBoASSA2NYi14uIsKMrMK9FI08gEKgYA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
ṁLṁṘNḣḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HORh8gfrhzht/DHYuB6P///4amBgA)

#### Explanation

```
          Implicit input, e.g 4
      ḣ   Range from 1 to n                               [1,2,3,4]
     ḣ    Prefixes                                        [[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
  ṁ       Map and then concatenate
   ṘN     Repeat each number in each list by its index    [[],[1],[1,2,2],[1,2,2,3,3,3],[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]]
                                                          [1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
ṁ         Map and then sum
 L        Length (of number: 10 -> 2)                     26
```

Comment: Oh another Husk solution :) Didn't see your submission when posting mine, same bytecount but they're sufficiently different, so I'll leave mine here too.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
Σ∫mS*Lḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziRx2rc4O1fB7uWPz//39DAwMA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
         -- implicit input N                        | 10
  m   ḣ  -- map the following function over [1..N]  | [1,2,3,4]
   S*L   --   multiply length of number by itself   | [1,2,3,4] (only important for numbers ≥ 10)
 ∫       -- prefix sums                             | [0,1,3,6,10]
Σ        -- sum                                     | 20
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

*Another one bytes the dust thanks to Jonathan Frech.*

```python
f=lambda n:n and sum(i*len(`i`)for i in range(n+1))+f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYnBCoMwEAXvfsUed2sKieJF8EtKwRRNXdCnxPTg18ecOjBzmeNKy44m5zCsfvtMntCDPCY6fxvrY53Bo44S9khKCooe35lRO5E6MJ5O8v@9nGlMa5w1nS0tdvbdV1Q4oiJxYBXJNw)

Not short but eh... what the heck.

Comment: `len(\`i\`)*i for` -> `i*len(\`i\`)for`.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUcHPqrg0V0PDT7dON09TK08rJzVPIyEvQTMtv0ghTyEzT6EoMS89VcNQx0/bUFPzP0g4HiRsqGOkY6xjaKBjagAkgdjUwKqgKDOvRCFNI17zPwA), non-recursive.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n)].reduce(x=>x+(++y+"").length*y*n--,y=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQu7SayRxatlHoHNFCbOiDjKEVenp773Kfyz6d96Mlbtx8lBwDU4g7QBNjFyKaU3IVBFdKvL2eoRhbFChVVdchBZb9Ofrai9ZDNSM2hAmx/Q)

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 20 bytes

```
q~),(\{),{_s,*+}*+}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOU0cjplpTpzq@WEdLuxaIVP//BwA)

The number is passed in the "input" field.

Ungolfed explanation: (example input = 2)

```
q~),(\{),{_s,*+}*+}%                                             | Stack:
q                     read input as string                       | "2"
 ~                    eval input (add it to stack as integer)    | 2
  )                   add 1                                      | 3
   ,                  range (convert to array with values 0...N) | [0, 1, 2]
    (                 pop first item of array                    | [1, 2] 0
     \                swap top two values of stack               | 0 [1, 2]
      {           }   for each item in array...                  | 0 1
       )              add 1                                      | 0 2
        ,             range (convert to array with values 0...N) | 0 [0, 1]
         {     }      for every element in the array...          | 0 0
          _           duplicate                                  | 0 0 0
           s          convert to string                          | 0 0 "0"
            ,         get length of string                       | 0 0 1
             *        multiply                                   | 0 0
              +       add                                        | 0 1
                *     fold                                       | 0 1
                 +    add                                        | 1
                   %  repeat                                     | 4
```

It seems hard when explained lol.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 39 bytes

```r
function(n)sum(nchar(rep(1:n,n:1*1:n)))
```

[Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/##DYhBCoAwDMC@00oPG7LLwMeM4lDQWjp38PW1hyQQ8755n8Lv@QgIjnmD8NEMbFfIVUhqXqKI6KOpXh9w/JVyopLCQUlIHf0H)

Simple algorithm; I observed, as most did, that for `i` in `1:n`, `i` is repeated `i*(n-i+1)` times. So I create that vector, count the number of characters in each, and sum them.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>50</s> 42 bytes

*Updated: now basically a port of what other answers are doing.*

```js
f=(n,i=1)=>n&&`${n}`.length*n*i+f(n-1,i+1)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,i=1)=>n&&`${n}`.length*n*i+f(n-1,i+1)

console.log(f(1))   // 1
console.log(f(2))   // 4
console.log(f(3))   // 10
console.log(f(10))  // 230
console.log(f(50))  // 42190
console.log(f(100)) // 339240
console.log(f(150)) // 1295790
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 24 bytes

```
[:+/[:+/\[:(*#@":"0)1+i.
```

Similar high-level approach to dzaima's APL answer, translated into J, except we calculate the number's length by turning it into a string first instead of taking logs, and we get to use J's hook to multiply that length by the number itself: `(*#@":"0)`.  After that it's just the sum of the scan sum.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P91WTyHaSlsfhGOirTS0lB2UrJQMNA21M/W4UpMz8hXSFQxhDCMYwxguZYBgGfz/DwA)

Comment: ``1(#.]*#\*#\.)1#@":@+i.`` also works for 22 bytes

Comment: @miles That's clever -- it took me a bit to figure it out.  How long have been programming in J for?

Comment: A bit after I joined code-golf. I don't actually use it to write any real programs as no I know would be able to read it, but I do use it as an advanced desktop calculator now, and usually always have a window open to calculate something.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 36 bytes

```perl6
{[+] 1..*Z*($_...1).map:{.chars*$_}}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZY5NTsMwEIX3PsUsIpSfMq2dpChERWzZs@JHUXCmIlJ@rDhFoJKzcBBYcRQuEuzUrNjY7z1/88aKhmY7HzTByxZlzto3OJN9RbCbj/fRI3DE8C70vQIReYBtqS6PKJ/LQYdeMU2z4a9H0iPsoKk70r5jGMA7yr598tcPVbQOvj/xphtX4BVsYnbdrRnKmWrKDqKlIWf7fnBl51fge3WnDnaCXhXJkSojK9IyAFtea7DfdFTwH2PTzAHg5@MLzM2E04nR8V@@McYe1ojYCGCps4ng2el5s/g4zkSyBOkp4CJLLyzyCw)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [+]               # reduce the following using &infix:«+»

    1 .. *          # Range from 1 to infinity

    Z*              # zip using &infix:«*»

    ( $_ ... 1 )    # sequence from the input down to 1
    .map:           # for each one
    { .chars * $_ } # multiply the number of digits with itself
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 31 bytes

```
{f={seq 1,_}f|f|[#`$_`*_1]|sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfzv9r86zba6OLVQwVAnvjatJq0mWjlBJT5BK94wtqa4NLf2f25iZp5CNZcCEBQUZeaVKBSUFmdoGJoaaCrUKLhpaHLV/gcA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <strike>51</strike> 50 bytes

```py
lambda n:sum(~k*(k-n)*len(`k+1`)for k in range(n))
```

Comment: @LeakyNun Why? I developed this answer myself. I didn't even check the other answers.

Comment: This doesn't even output the right answer, gives 0 for n=1, 3 for n=2 and 14 for n=3

Comment: @HalvardHummel Oops, messed up a sign and forgot a +1. Fixed now.

Comment: I see that you finally understood the patern! Is there a way to test your code online or the other Python 2 answer covers this, too?

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL], <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```apl
{+/≢¨⍕¨↑,/(/⍨¨⍳¨⍳⍵)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P03hUdsEhWpt/Uediw6teNQ7FUi0TdTR19B/1LsCJLAZTDzq3apZ@/9R31Sw8rRDKxSAgqZccAEFQwMkjqnBfwA)

Explanation:

```apl
{+/≢¨⍕¨↑,/(/⍨¨⍳¨⍳⍵)}
{                  } anonymous function with right argument named ⍵
                ⍳⍵   range 1 to right arg
              ⍳¨     for each, range 1 to it
             ¨       for each
           /⍨          for each item, repeat right arg left arg times
          (       )  take that and
        ,/           join the sub-arrays together
       ↑             convert from a nested array to a simple array (or something like that, I don't quite understand it :p)
     ⍕¨              convert each number to a char-array (aka string version)
   ≢¨                get length of each
 +/                  sum that together
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 66 bytes

```
Tr[1^(f=Flatten)[IntegerDigits/@f@(a=Array)[a[#~Table~#&,#]&,#]]]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
õõÈ*sÊÃxx
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9fXIKnPKw3h4&input=OA==) or [test all numbers from 1 to 150](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9V/19cgqc8rDeHg=&input=MTUw).

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
õõ
```

Generate an array of integers from 1 to `U` and then generate sub-arrays from 1 to each integer.

```
È   Ã
```

Pass the elements of each sub-array through a function.

```
*sÊ
```

Convert the current element to a string (`s`), get it's length (`Ê`) and multiply it by the element.

```
xx
```

Reduce the main array by addition after first doing the same to each sub-array.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>66</s> <s>51</s></sub> 50 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from the range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE

```vba
For i=1To[A1]:For j=1To i:s=s+j*Len(j):Next j,i:?s
```

### Alternate Version, 94 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input,`n`, from range `[A1]` constructs the `GUA(n)` and outputs the length of it to the VBE immediate window

```vba
[B1].Resize([A1],1)="=IfError(Offset(B1,-1,0)&Rept(Row(),Row()),1)":?[Len(TextJoin("",1,B:B))]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 21 bytes

```
[:|[a|[c|A=A+!c$}?_lA
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```
ＩΣＥ⊕ＮΣＥ⊕ι×λＬＩλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUDDMy@5KDU3Na8kNQXILigt8SvNTUot0tDU1FHApiYTKB6SmZtarJGjo@CTmpdekgExMEcTBqz//zc0@K9b9l@3OAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Using `Sum` saved me 4 bytes. Explanation:

```
  Ｅ⊕Ｎ           Map from 0 to the input (loop variable i)
      Ｅ⊕ι       Map from 0 to i (loop variable l)
            Ｉλ  Cast l to string
           Ｌ    Take the length
         ×λ     Multiply by l
     Σ          Sum the results
 Σ              Sum the results
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Comment: :| Sum sums numbers in the strings when given string arguments

Comment: @ASCII-only It wasn't that, it was just printing a `Σ` instead...

Comment: @ASCII-only Also, best I can do with `Sum` is still 18 bytes: `Print(Cast(Sum(Map(InclusiveRange(1, InputNumber()), Sum(Map(InclusiveRange(1, i), Times(l, Length(Cast(l)))))))));`

Comment: [wait you keep forgetting `Incremented` :P](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npXv96x5tGr1@z1LH3VNfb9nHZx9bufh6UDpc7vP7T7feb7z/39DAwA)

Comment: @ASCII-only I tried sum of product but that was 17 bytes: `≔⊕ＮθＩΣＥθ×⁻θι×ιＬＩι`. However, using `Incremented` instead of `InclusiveRange` shaves 4 bytes off my previous comment!

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 13 bytes

```
R♂R♂i⌠;n⌡Mεjl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/z/o0cwmEM581LPAOu9Rz0Lfc1uzcv7/NzQAAA)

Explanation:

```
R♂R♂i⌠;n⌡Mεjl
R              range(1, n+1)
 ♂R            range(1, x+1) for x in previous
   ♂i          flatten into 1D list
     ⌠;n⌡M     for x in list:
      ;n       repeat x x times
          εj   concatenate to string
            l  length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>82</s> <s>49</s> 43 bytes

```
[range(.)+1|range(.)+1|"\(.)"*.|length]|add
```

Expanded

```
[   range(.)+1        # for i=1 to N
  | range(.)+1        # for j=1 to i
  | "\(.)"*.          # "j" copied j times
  | length            # convert to length
] | add               # add lengths
```

Sample Run

```
$ jq -Mr '[range(.)+1|range(.)+1|"\(.)"*.|length]|add' <<< "150"
1295790
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8b1rzP7ooMS89VUNPU9uwBompFAOklbT0anJS89JLMmJrElNS/v//l19QkpmfV/xfVzevNCdHNzOvoLQEyClKLNfNLy0BcgA) also [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/eo2lWPgLj0)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>94</strike> <strike>80</strike> 74 bytes

```cs
n=>{int b=0,a=0,i;while(a++<n)for(i=0;i++<a;)b+=(i+"").Length*i;return b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY6xasMwEEDn6CuOTFKcGich00VZAp1SKDSQWVbU5MA9EUluKcbf7opCoUPs4Q4ej8edjU/WBze0kfgKb98xuQ8U/6k8Et9R2MbECK@diMkksvDcst0RpyXktYcTaBhY77tMUOtqafIQft2ocdIUxY7Vuw@SdIWUyaCqCy2pmM9VeXR8TbcFYXCpDQw19gOKv0Ofni7wYoilEp2YHTxH37jyHCi5/JqTJ7lSCh@b9ajZjJpVNaq21UQ1lU12v7IX/fAD)

I was hoping to find a direct solution like what [@kamoroso94's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143614/73579) started, but gave up as I was spending too much time on it. There probably is a way of doing it, but the formula needs to adjust for every magnitude step.

#### Acknowledgements

14 bytes saved thanks to @someone

6 bytes saved thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: `n=>{int b=0,a=0,i;for(;a++<n;)for(i=0;i++<a;)b+=i.ToString().Length*i;return b;}` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BagIxEIbPzVPMMenaZW3paYyXgicFwQXP2TTqgJ3QJCvIss@@pgXBg7uHGebj4@cfG9@sD25oI/ERdteY3A@KRyrXxL8o7NnECNtOxGQSWVi1bBfEaQZ5LaEGDQPrZZcJGl3NTB7Cgw8STVEsGNXfTbpCymhQNYWmsva7FHKXVOXa8TGdXgmDS21gaLAfUNzrLp6@YWOIpRKdePnyHP3ZlftAyeUHnazlXCl8bt5HzceomVej6rOaSE3FJnP/shf9cAM "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online") for 80 bytes and performance.

Comment: `i.ToString()` can be `(i+"")` to save some more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 73 bytes

```
f=->(t){(1..t).map{|n|(1..n).map{|n|Array.new(n,n)}}.flatten.join.length}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 28 bytes

```
[~>[~>[:rep]"!]"!flat''#`#']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P7rODoSsilILYpUUgSgtJ7FEXV05QVk99r@DVRoXl6GBQp2dgoapgYKhARCbGmgq6ChEWymkASl1BV07IJGVn5mnkF9aEquQm1jwHwA)

Some might ask, "At which point are aliases unreadable?" If this isn't close, you have a very liberal definition of "readability".

### Explanation

```
[~>[~>[:rep]"!]"!flat''#`#']    input: N
 ~>[          ]"!               for each number K from 1 to N
    ~>[    ]"!                  for each number J from 1 to K
       :rep                     repeat J J times
                 flat           flatten the resultant array
                     ''#`       join by the empty string
                         #'     get the length of said string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n).map{|x|[x]*x*=-x-~n}*''=~/$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQTy9PUy83saC6pqImuiJWq0LLVrdCty6vVktd3bZOX0W/9j9IkaEBVFVRTYFCdJFOWnRRbGztfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
:ttP*Y"10&YlQks
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36qkJEArUsnQQC0yJzC7@P9/Q1MDAA)

Explanation:

```
:                range 1:input (implicit input)
 tt              duplicate twice
   P             reverse
    *            multiply elementwise
     Y"          runlength decoding
       10&Yl     log10
            Qk   increment and floor
              s  sum (implicit output)
```

Comment: That logarithm is expensive :-) You can replace it by converting to string, removing spaces, length: [`:ttP*Y"VXzn`](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36qkJEArUiksoirv/39DAwMA)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>48</s>, 44 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to for + curly braces trick

```
for((;r+=t+=n*${#n},++n<=$1;));{ :;};echo $r
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 7 bytes

```
@@D×JJl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/38HB5fB0L6@c//8NDQz@AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `JL`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RJF
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVJKRiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTMmZmxhZ3M9Skw=)

Or, 5 bytes flagless: [`RJFJl`](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVJKRkpsJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MyZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
RJFJl  # Implicit input
R      # Range [1..input]
 J     # Join into a string
  F    # All substrings
   J   # Join into a string
    l  # Length of the string
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,i=1:x and x*i*len(str(x))+f(x-1,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxDoMwDADAmb7Cow2uFBexIPES1CEVjWoJDAoZzOtThrvjKr/d@lrTtMbts0Rw1klGh2gLeKvt@jU8S0Yn6hL6U1g7oZr2DApqMAu/uGcJPIT72xDe46M5slrBhEpU/w)

Comment: inb4 [44 bytes on Python 2](https://tio.run/##DcQxCoAwDADAWV@RsdUITcVF8CUiWNFiQKOIQ3x97XB3f@9@iU8pDkc4lzWAIg/UKwRZQSuujk3MrLOto9GGkGuyKV4PMLDASOixRXLYuXzWuakvi/theU00bG36AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
Sum[i⌊1+Log10@i⌋,{j,#},{i,j}]&
```

Comment: this is not what the question is asking...

Comment: fails for n=100.Please read more carefully, check the test cases and give a final answer

Comment: @JoseZaman my bad, sir. It's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 33 + 1 (-p) = 34 bytes

```perl
map{map$\+=$_*y///c,1..$_}1..$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saAaiFVitG1V4rUq9fX1k3UM9fRU4mshZPX//4YG//ILSjLz84r/6xYAAA)

Comment: maybe can avoid outer loop `$\+=$x+=$_*y///c`

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
LLD×Jg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx8fl8HSv9P//DU0NAA)

**Explanation**

```
L        # range [1 ... input]
 L       # for each range [1 ... x]
  D      # duplicate
   ×     # repeat each in the first list a number of times determined by the second list
    J    # join to string
     g   # length
```

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, 36 bytes

```
{x:Int->(1..x).flatMap{1..it}.sum()}
```

Test:

```
val GAU = {x:Int->(1..x).flatMap{1..it}.sum()}
GAU(5)
=> 35
```

Comment: GAU(10)=220 does not equal 230 :)

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 12 bytes

```
{{]Ø.*}S.}S.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/7@6OvbwDD2t2mA9IPr//7@hBQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 76 bytes

```java
n->{int r=0,i=0,j;for(;i++<n;)for(j=0;j++<i;r+=(j+"").length()*j);return r;}
```

I have the feeling this can be golfed with a more arithmetic approach, instead of using `String#length`..

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hU67DsIwDNz5CospoVAVEJMpfwALI2IIIUBCcavURUKo315SHiOKZFu273R3Tt3VpKwMueO104Wqa1grS88BgCU2/qS0gU1/vh@gRT9JYvi0oUPVrNhq2ABBDh1NVs@e4vNsbEM7PJVeoE2SJaHsd5dn6MJp0Se5cMlwKNPC0JkvQo6cRG@48QQe2w4/DlVzKILD1@he2iPcQkixZW/pvNuDkp@E20fN5paWDadVgLggQakWU/nO@xefRfB5BJ9mEcIiiypEGT@NdtB2Lw)

```java
n->{                        // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int r=0,                  //  Result-integer
      i=0,j;                //  Index integers
  for(;i++<n;)              //  Loop (1) from 0 to the input (exclusive)
    for(j=0;                //   Reset `j` to 0
        j++<i;              //   Inner loop (2) from 0 to `i` (exlusive)
      r+=                   //    Append the result-String with:
         (j+"").length()*j  //     The length of `j` multiplied by `j`
    );                      //   End of inner loop (2)
                            //  End of inner loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;                 //  Return result-String
}                           // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```scala
(1 to n).map(i=>(i+"").length*i*(n+1-i)).sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY9NT8MwDIbP7a/woh6cLa2atBOqRCdx4gRIcNg5lGwEdWlJAkKq@tuLu1389crvY4dO93oZ3r9MF@FJWwfmLxr3EeBhHGFKk1/dQzQhBmjhzXwjSiG5QCVqipWQJSVZClWtxb4UtZLNbVaKqmpUfW1IkKrZ35HE0@Q0eEB0ouNwn9/c@cq6wryJhJoWlBAHcLy46BFte0C7Y4wXvXHn@Lm1W3Q7mVvOi/BzWZJkpvXRWxd7h4FlDvIDZKsXZpM9AVLZtgRk3eA9PcvA9MEAO76@PD9u2MwZHTan8/IP)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
RRx`€VV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8oqCLhUdOasLD///8bGgAA)

**Explanation:**

```
RRx`€VV    Example input: 3
R          Range. Result: [1, 2, 3]
 R         Range (vectorizes). Result: [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
    €      Apply to €ach...
  x`       Repeat each number itself times. Result: [[[1]], [[1], [2, 2]], [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]]
     VV    Concatenate them into one big friendly number. Result: 1122122333
```

Answer (score 0):

### [PocoLithp](https://github.com/andrakis/PocoLithp), 111 bytes

```
(define gau(#(N I)(if(!(defined I))(gau N 1)(if(!= N 0)(+(*(*(length(expl(str N)))N)I)(gau(- N 1)(+ I 1)))N))))
```

More readable version:

```
(define gau (# (N I) (begin
        (if (! (defined I))      ;; I not supplied, recurse with I set to 1
                (gau N 1)
                (begin           ;; I supplied, calculate
                        (define A (length (expl (str N))))  ;; `N`.length
                        (if (!= N 0)
                            ;; N != 0, head recursive calculation
                            (+ (* (* A N) I) (gau (- N 1) (+ I 1)))
                            ;; N == 0, return it
                             N)
                )
        )
)))
```

Usage:

```
(gau 123) => 662505
(gau 256) => 7532088
```

Named function `gau`, which takes 1 or 2 parameters. If called with 1 parameter, calls self with 2nd parameter set to 1. This implements the default variables used in other implementations.

This could possibly be made tail recursive, but it would likely be even longer than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 93 bytes

```
$a=@();$b=@();1..$n|% $_{$i=0;Do{$a+=$_;$i++}while($i-ne$_);$b+=$a-join''};($b-join'').Length
```

Code exploded a bit:

```
$inputNum = 10
$numbers = 1..$inputNum
$array = @()
$bigArray = @()
Foreach ($number in $numbers){
    $i = 0
    Do {
        $array += $number
        $i++
    }
    while ($i -ne $number)
    $bigArray += $array -join ''
}
($bigArray -join '').Length
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 29 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
1$`¶
1
1$%`¶
1
$.%_
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLy5DLUCXh0DYwrQphqOipxnPp/f9vyGXEZcxlaMBlagAA)

#### Explanation

```
.+
$*
```

Convert input to unary.

```
1
1$`¶
```

Turn the input `N` into a range from `1` to `N` by inserting the prefix up to each `1` after it, together with a linefeed.

```
1
1$%`¶
```

Do the same thing to each value in that range. This time we use `` $%` ``, which is just the prefix on the current line. So this gives `1, 1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4, ...` (in unary). Now all we need to do is repeat each value accordingly and converting to decimal.

```
1
$.%_
```

This is done by replacing each `1` with the length of the line its on.

```
.
```

Finally we count the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 32 bytes

```ruby
:+|:*&(:+|:*&~:*%-[I])|:join|:+@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWNxWstGustNQ0IFSdlZaqbrRnrGaNVVZ-Zl6NlbYDRN3yAgW3aEODWAhvwQIIDQA)

### Explanation

```
:+ | :* & (:+ | :* & ~:* % -[I]) | :join | :+@

:+ | :* & (                    )                # Range, then map with...
           :+ | :* &                            #   Range, then map with...
                     ~:* % -[I]                 #     [n] * n
                                 | :join | :+@  # Then join all elements and get length
```